# Why is the objects data being displayed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am only  asking for the page to show a link to the website, but something is sending extra information. 
[image: The extra information is under the link "testing123"]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Sorry about not providing code. I figured that it was an easy fix that many people have probably run into before.

Comment: It probably is an easy fix but people still need to see your code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a feeling you are looping in the view with something like `<%= posts.each do |post| %>` if you remove the `=` such as `<% posts.each do |post| %>` the data will no longer be displayed.

In very simplified terms:

`<%=` means display this data. `each` will return the original object so you are telling it to display this object. `<%` means do this but don't display.

Comment: Wow what a life saver! Thanks a ton :)